# Why is my Stata code taking so long to run?

Tags: stata, coding-efficiency

I have data on employment spells of individuals at different companies. My goal is to create variables that measure an individual’s network strength and size based on overlapping employment spells with other individuals at other companies. My data is relatively large. I have more than 16,000,000 observations for over 350,000 individuals. I have written the below Stata code which produces the required output, but unfortunately it takes very long to run. It would take one month to complete with my data. There must be a way to make the code more efficient, but I cannot figure out how. I would be most grateful if you could please help. I use Stata 16.

In what follows, I will provide a minimal, reproducible example.

First, input and save a raw toy dataset:

```
clear
input byte(individual_id company_id) double(fiscal_year_end year)
1 1 18992 2011
1 1 19358 2012
1 2 18992 2011
1 2 19358 2012
1 2 19723 2013
1 2 20088 2014
2 1 18992 2011
2 1 19358 2012
2 1 19723 2013
2 3 19358 2012
2 3 19723 2013
3 2 19723 2013
3 2 20088 2014
4 1 18992 2011
4 1 19358 2012
5 1 19723 2013
5 1 20088 2014
5 3 19358 2012
5 3 19723 2013
end
format %td fiscal_year_end
save raw_data.dta, replace
```

Second, create temporary datasets with active individual IDs (during last three years) for each year:
*[Rationale: I would like for individuals to not be included in someone’s network if they are inactive for some time. This is supposed to proxy for things like retirement.]*

```
* Restrict to unique individual year pairs
keep individual_id year
duplicates drop

* Fill in missing individual year observations
fillin individual_id year

* Sort data by individual ID and year
sort individual_id year

* Generate indicator for active during last three years
gen active_3yrs = (_fillin==0)
by individual_id (year): replace active_3yrs = 1 if _fillin[_n-1]==0 | _fillin[_n-2]==0  | _fillin[_n-3]==0

* Drop observations for inactive individuals
drop if active_3yrs==0

* Save temporary datasets with active individual IDs for each year
levelsof year, local(years)
foreach i in `years' {
    preserve
    keep if year==`i'
    keep individual_id
    save active_`i'.dta, replace
    restore
    drop if year==`i'
}
```

Third, create a temporary dataset with IDs of individuals who were at at least two companies:
*[Rationale: Otherwise they cannot have an external network]*

```
* Load raw data
use raw_data.dta, replace
keep individual_id company_id
duplicates drop
duplicates tag individual_id, gen(tmp)
drop if tmp==0
drop tmp
keep individual_id
duplicates drop
rename individual_id focal_id
sort focal_id
save ids.dta, replace
```

Forth, create temporary datasets with potential network observations for each individual-year pair:

```
forvalues i = 1/`=_N' {
    * Load temporary dataset with individual IDs
    use ids.dta, clear
    
    * Restrict to focal individual ID and store it as local macro
    keep if _n==`i'
    quietly summarize focal_id
    local x "`r(mean)'"
    
    * Load temporary datasets with base information for network variable creation
    use raw_data.dta, clear
    
    * Generate focal individual ID variable
    gen focal_id = `x'
    format focal_id %12.0f
    
    * Keep observations for individuals who work are at the same company during the same fiscal year as the focal individual
    gen tmp = (individual_id==focal_id)
    sort company_id fiscal_year_end
    by company_id fiscal_year_end: egen tmp2 = max(tmp)
    drop if tmp==1
    drop if tmp2==0
    drop tmp tmp2
    
    * Save as temporary datasets (if dataset is not empty)
    capture assert _N>0
    if !_rc {
            save tmp_individual_`i'.dta, replace
        }
        else {
            // do nothing
        }
}
```

Fifth, clean temporary datasets with potential network observations for each individual-year pair:
*[NB: Drop observations for inactive directors and that occur after the focal year. Then create network size and strength variables and keep unique company-fiscal end pairs for focal year.]*

```
* Define programme that calculates network size and strength variables
capture program drop network_size_strength
program network_size_strength
    quietly tab individual_id if rr_company_id!=company_id & rr_fiscal_year_end>=fiscal_year_end
    gen network_size = r(r)
    gen network_strength = r(N) / r(r)
end

* Load temporary dataset with IDs of individuals who were at at least two companies
use ids.dta, clear

forvalues i = 1/`=_N' {
    * Load temporary dataset (if existing)
    capture confirm file "tmp_individual_`i'.dta"
    if !_rc {
        use tmp_individual_`i'.dta, clear
        
        levelsof year, local(years)
        foreach j in `years' {
            * Preserve data
            preserve
                
            * Observations after focal year
            drop if year>`j'
            
            * Drop inactive investors
            merge m:1 individual_id using active_`j'.dta, nogen keep(match)
            
            * Generate network size and strength variables
            rangerun network_size_strength, int(fiscal_year_end . .) sprefix(rr_) use(individual_id company_id fiscal_year_end)
            
            * Keep observations for focal year
            keep if year==`j'
            
            * Keep variables of interest
            keep company_id fiscal_year_end focal_id network_size network_strength
            
            * Rename individual ID variable
            rename focal_id individual_id
            
            * Drop duplicates
            duplicates drop
            
            * Save as temporary dataset
            save tmp_individual_`i'_`j'.dta, replace
            
            * Restore data
            restore
        }
        * Remove temporary dataset
        rm tmp_individual_`i'.dta
        }
        else {
            // do nothing
        }
}
```

Sixth, append all temporary datasets:

```
* Load temporary datasets with base information for network variable creation
use raw_data.dta, clear

* Store unique year values in local macro
levelsof year, local(years)

* Load temporary dataset with IDs of individuals who were at at least two companies
use ids.dta, clear

forvalues i = 1/`=_N' {
    foreach j in `years' {
        * Drop focal ID variable (if existing)
        capture confirm variable focal_id
        if !_rc {
            drop focal_id
        }
        else {
            // do nothing
        }
        
        * Check if temporary dataset exists
        capture confirm file "tmp_individual_`i'_`j'.dta"
        if !_rc {
            * Append temporary dataset
            append using tmp_individual_`i'_`j'.dta
            
            * Delete temporary dataset
            rm tmp_individual_`i'_`j'.dta
        }
        else {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}

* Save data
save network_variables.dta, replace
```

Seventh, create final data by merging to raw data:

```
merge 1:1 individual_id company_id fiscal_year_end using raw_data.dta, nogen keep(match using)
order individual_id company_id fiscal_year_end year, first
sort individual_id company_id fiscal_year_end
save final_data.dta, replace
```

The final data should look like this:

```
clear
input double individual_id byte company_id double(fiscal_year_end year network_size network_strength)
1 1 18992 2011 0                  .
1 1 19358 2012 0                  .
1 2 18992 2011 .                  .
1 2 19358 2012 .                  .
1 2 19723 2013 2                  2
1 2 20088 2014 2                  2
2 1 18992 2011 0                  .
2 1 19358 2012 1                  1
2 1 19723 2013 1                  2
2 3 19358 2012 2                  2
2 3 19723 2013 3 1.6666666666666667
3 2 19723 2013 .                  .
3 2 20088 2014 .                  .
4 1 18992 2011 .                  .
4 1 19358 2012 .                  .
5 1 19723 2013 1                  2
5 1 20088 2014 .                  .
5 3 19358 2012 0                  .
5 3 19723 2013 1                  1
end
format %td fiscal_year_end
```

Comment: This is mostly speculation, but it seems like there is a lot of writing `.dta` files to disk involved, which I imagine is a time and memory intensive task. Maybe a more experienced user can comment, but it might be more efficient to save data as tempfiles (see `tempfile`) or in another way that avoids the need to write so many datasets to disk.

Comment: If you have Stata 16 and enough memory you can use `frames` and `frlink` to reduce the number of times you write to disk (see `help frames` and `help frlink`. Additionally, you can explore `ftools` (see `ssc install ftools`) and `gtools` (see `ssc install gtools`). If you have Stata 16 then just add that information to the post and I'll be happy to contribute an answer (this is so that the post doesn't get marked as answered if the Stata 16 answer doesn't help you).

Comment: Many thanks, @Cybernike! I used ```tempfile``` and it does indeed speed the code up.

Comment: @ArthurMorris, yes, I use Stata 16. If you could contribute an answer, that would be most appreciated. I have also amended my original post accordingly.

Comment: Upon further review: most of the time is probably spend in the loop that appends the individual datasets, and there is no frame-based alternative to `append`.